# What does PHP syntax $var1[] = $var2 mean?

Tags: php, syntax

What does PHP syntax `$var1[] = $var2` mean?

Note the `[]` after `$var1` varable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php. look carefully for the first **Note:** section

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - see "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax"

Comment: It means `$var1` is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and is receiving the value of `$var2` to it's next available position (that's the reason of the empty `[]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `$var1` is an array, and this syntax means you are inserting `$var2` into a new element at the end of the array.

So if your array had 2 elements before, like this:

```
$var1=( 1 => 3, 2 => 4)
```

and the value of $var2 was 5, it would not look like this:

```
$var1=( 1 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => 5)
```

It also means that if $var2 was an array itself, you have just created a two dimensional array. Assuming the following:

```
$var1=( 1 => 3, 2 => 4)
$var2=( 1 => 10, 2=>20)
```

doing a `$var1[]=$var2;` wouls result in an array like this:

```
$var1=( 1 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => (1 =>10, 2 => 20))
```

As an aside, if you haven't used multi-dimensional arrays yet, accessing the data is quite simple. If I wanted to use the value 20 from our new array, I could do it in this manner:

```
echo $var1[3][2];
```

Note the second set of square brackets - basically you are saying I want to access element two of the array inside element 3 of the $var1 array.

On that note, there is one thing to be aware of. If you are working with multi-dimensional arrays, this syntax can catch you out inside a loop structure of some sort. Lets say you have a two dimensional array where you store some records and want to get more from the database:

```
$var1 = ( 
    1 => (id =>1, age => 25, posts => 40),
    2 => (id =>2, age => 29, posts => 140),
    3 => (id =>3, age => 32, posts => 12)
    )
```

A loop like this following:

```
while($row=someDatabaseRow)
{
    $var1[]=$row['id']; // value 4
    $var1[]=$row['age']; // value 21
    $var1[]=$row['posts']; // value 34
}
```

will infact insert a new element for every execution, hence your array would end up looking like this:

```
$var1 = ( 
    1 => (id =>1, age => 25, posts => 40),
    2 => (id =>2, age => 29, posts => 140),
    3 => (id =>3, age => 32, posts => 12),
    4 => 4,
    5 => 21,
    6 => 34
    )
```

The correct way would be to assemble the array first, then append it to your current array to maintain the strucutre, like this:

```
while($row=someDatabaseRow)
{
    $tempArr= array();
    $tempArr[]=$row['id']; // value 4
    $tempArr[]=$row['age']; // value 21
    $tempArr[]=$row['posts']; // value 34
    $var1[]=$tempArr;
}
```

Now your array would look like you expected, namely:

```
$var1 = ( 
    1 => (id =>1, age => 25, posts => 40),
    2 => (id =>2, age => 29, posts => 140),
    3 => (id =>3, age => 32, posts => 12)
    4 => (id =>4, age => 21, posts => 34)
    )
```

Comment: `$var1[]=$tempArr;` -- this would only push the last item (i.e. `$row['posts']`) to `$var1`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Very well spotted. I changed the code with what I meant to do. Can't believe no-one picked that up before you did! +1

Answer (score 2):

It means that you're pushing the value of `var2` to array `var1`.

Answer (score 2):

That's shorthand for [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

It will make `$var1` and array (if it isn't already) and push `$var2` in to it.

Answer (score 1):

It basically makes $var1 an array and adding to it's end a value of $var2.

```
$var1 = NULL;
$var2 = 'abc';
$var1[] = $var2;
```

$var1 is now an array containing one value: 'abc'