# Comparison operators that I haven't seen before

Tags: javascript

I am trying to decipher the following line of JavaScript code:

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined") ? !(delay_start_qs === "false") : true;
```

Specifically the `?` followed by the `!`. Is that a comparison operator?

Comment: no it is a ternary operator, a short way of writing an if statement

Comment: The `?` is part of the ternary operator, the `!` is a negation operator applied to the result of the first branch, and `:` is the second part of the ternary operator.

Comment: If this should be closed, why not this -. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774863/what-does-php-syntax-var1-var2-mean ?? [a real RTFM getting incredible upvoting in the answers, and certainly asked 100 times before] It seems rather random and very unclear how and when which questions people are voting for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined") ? !(delay_start_qs === "false") : true;
```

is the same as

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined") ? delay_start_qs !== "false" : true;
```

because `!(x === y)` is equivalent to `x !== y` when neither x nor y are NaN.  And the whole is the same as

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs === "undefined") ? true : delay_start_qs !== "false";
```

because `x ? y : z` is the same as `!x ? z : y`.  And the whole is the same as

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs === "undefined") || delay_start_qs !== "false";
```

because `x ? true : y` is the same as `x || y` when `typeof x === "boolean"`.  And the whole is the same as

```
if (typeof delay_start_qs === "undefined" || delay_start_qs !== "false") {
  delay_start = true;
} else {
  delay_start = false;
}
```

because `a = x ? y : z;` is a statement that uses x to decide which of y or z to assign to a.

Comment: This is a great breakdown -- I am following the steps...

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple **ternary operator** in play.

```
delay_start = (typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined") 
                                ? !(delay_start_qs === "false") : true;
```

Lets break it..

`(typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined")` // If delay_start_qs is undefined

if above condition is true then  `delay_start = !(delay_start_qs === "false") ;`

otherwise    `delay_start = true;`

The same can be written as a for loop

```
if(typeof delay_start_qs !== "undefined") {
    delay_start = !(delay_start_qs === "false") ;
} else {
    delay_start = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the ternary operator.

```
value = condition ? <if condition is true statement> : <else statement>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x ? y : z
```

Read the above as:

```
if(x) {
  y;
} else {
  z;
}
```

or:

```
if x then y else z
```

The `!` means `not`.  It has no relation to the `?`.  So what you're looking at is more like this:

```
if x then (not y) else z
```